# How to call gtk_container_remove() on a Gtk.Container in PyGObject?

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

In a PyGObject project, I am trying to remove a widget from a [`GtkStatusbar`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/unstable/GtkStatusbar.html) using the gobject-introspection binding of [`gtk_container_remove ()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/unstable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-remove).

Normally when working with the GObject Introspection Python bindings, the method name is the same as the C function name, minus the "type prefix" and taking one less explicit argument. For example, I call [`gtk_box_pack_end ()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/unstable/GtkBox.html#gtk-box-pack-end) to add the widget that I later want to remove:

```
statusbar.pack_end(widget, False, True, 0)
```

When I try to remove the widget via `statusbar.remove(widget)`, I see:

```
...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: remove() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

One of the arguments is the implicit `self` and the other two arguments are apparently supposed to be numbers.

Here is the method's GIR:

```
<method name="remove" c:identifier="gtk_container_remove">
  <return-value transfer-ownership="none">
    <type name="none" c:type="void"/>
  </return-value>
  <parameters>
    <parameter name="widget" transfer-ownership="none">
      <type name="Widget" c:type="GtkWidget*"/>
    </parameter>
  </parameters>
</method>
```

How do I call the `gtk_container_remove ()` function in PyGObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gtk.Statusbar` override the `remove` function with another one with a different signature. You could try to destroy the widget, the container, the statusbar, will be notified and it will remove the widget, hoping you don't need it anymore.

Otherwise you could try: `Gtk.Container.remove(statusbar, widget)`.